Is 2 hr 25 min Layover time Singapore sufficient?
Flying Singapore Airlines from Chennai to Denpasar, Layover at Singapore is 2hr 25 min.

Flight MAA- SIN. SQ529 Wed 01/01/2025
Flight SIN- DPS  SQ936 Thu 02/01/2025


Is this booked as a single ticket?

Only a matter of time before people are going to be asking about the adequacy of a 12 hour layover and if that's enough time to make a connection.

Why are we downvoting a new user? It's a perfectly legitimate question asked in good faith, not everybody is a travel pro.

If the two flights are on the same ticket (which is the most likely, especially if you bought the trip from Singapore Airlines directly):

2h25 are more than enough for that connection. You even have time for some shopping and dining (but make sure you are at the gate at the requested time)
You should receive the boarding passes for both flights at initial check-in (but if the departure gate for your second gate is printed on it, double-check it when you land in SIN, it may have changed in the meantime, and it can still change afterwards)
Your luggage will be checked through to the final destination
You won't go through passport control, won't have to deal with your bags, won't have to go to check-in
If ever you don't have the boarding pass for the next flight (unlikely, but it happens) and you can't get it on your mobile either, you'll have to approach a transfer desk to get it
Security is performed at the gate (or group of gates).
So it's just a matter of exiting the aircraft (you end up directly in the departures area), checking the departure gate for your next flight, going there, and go through security there. Depending on the gate combination it may take anywhere between 5 and 30 minutes, I guess.
If your incoming flight is delayed but you can still make the second flight, you can probably expect staff at the gate to escort you to the departure gate so you don't get lost (though I'm not sure how you could)
If your incoming flight is so late that you can't make the second flight, they will rebook you on the next available flight. SQ have 6 flights a day on the SIN-DPS route, and Scoot (a subsidiary of SQ) 3 more, so while you may be delayed a few hours, there's no real risk for you.

If on the other hand for some unfathomable reason this is a self-transfer (the two flights are booked separately), while doable if all goes well, this would be extremely risky in case of any delays.

Yes, a layover of 2 hours and 25 minutes at Singapore Changi Airport should be sufficient for your connecting flight from Chennai (SQ529) to Denpasar (SQ936). Both flights typically operate from Terminal 2, making the transfer smoother in most cases. However, it also depends on potential delays and the efficiency of the airlines. In my experience, Singapore Airlines is generally reliable and punctual.
